# What is best way to retrieve cookie/session contents from third party website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

**CONTEXT**

I am building a web app which analyzes information on a user's site. I plan to do this by asking the user to add a JS snippet to their `<head>` which creates cookies that collect information about each visitor to that site.

**PROBLEM**

I would like to then send information that is held in this cookie back to my web app. I realize normally cookies cannot be accessed by anything other than code on the same domain, so I'm hoping that the JS snippet will read the content of that cookie and pass it back to my app - is this possible? What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Set the cookie from your own domain, the JavaScript in the head inserts a link to your domain. Have a look how Google does it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic pattern that's used by google analytics and most other website analysis tools as well as advertising modules. Your snippet, running on your user's site, can read/write cookies there. It can also make ajax calls to your own web service to communicate any data it gathers, including cookie contents. Your "app" doesn't run on your user's site, only the snippet (and any code it drags into the site).

Comment: Thank you Michel! For anyone else facing the same issue - this link is a useful start to developing embeddable javascript widgets... which is what you'll likely need to accomplish the above: https://www.coshx.com/blog/2015/02/19/developing-an-embeddable-javascript-widget-snippet-for-client-sites/